# Can't link text in <span> tag

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a template with a navigation made of span elements. I want to add a URL to one of the span elements that it opens a certain URL in a new tab. What am I doing wrong? (I'm a beginner in programming)

```html
<Tab>
  <img className="svg" src="/assets/img/svg/briefcase.svg" alt="briefcase" />
  <span href="url.html" className="menu_content">eindrücke</span>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Why are you using a React template that doesn't (seem to) do what you want it to do; can you modify it, to create anchors `<a>` instead of `<span>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spans are used to display text.

If you want to add a link you need to add an anchor element `<a>`.

You need to write:

```html
<a href='YOUR_LINK'>text_of_your_link</a>
```

Instead of :

```html
<span>your_text</span>
```

You can use `<a>` to link to other urls or to ids in your HTML.

If you want to link to an id in the same page you write:

```html
<a href='#YOUR_ID'>your_text</a>
```

The page will then scroll to the that id in your page.

If you want a link to go to a page and directly scroll to an id, your write:

```html
<a href='https://yourlinkurl.com/#THE_ID'>your_text</a>
```

If you want to add navigation inside of your react app, and add different URLs to the pages of your React app, you will need to add a library (like React Router).

In that library, you have custom components that you will use to navigate inside your app. They are used like this:

```html
<Link to='/your_local_url'>your_text</Link>
```

https://reactrouter.com

Comment: Thank you brother. Seems like I need to put way more time into this topic :D